# Set Image Source depending on ViewModels Type

Tags: c#, wpf, image, datatemplate

I have hierarchical data which I want to display inside a `TreeView`.
All those objects have a common base class and the Bindings work with that baseclass.
Now I want to show a different `Image` depending on the Type of the `ViewModel`.

Right now I have a `HierachicalDataTemplate` for that.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:ItemBaseViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Column="0"
               Height="12"
               Source="/Client;component/Images/icon.png" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding DisplayString}" />
    </Grid>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

What is the easiest way to display `bar.png` for BarViewModel and `foo.png` for FooViewModel? (Both of them are derived from ItemBaseViewModel)

Comment: Why not to have `DataTemplates` for derived types instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is when the difference can be distinguished by a property, which can be checked through a `DataTrigger`. For example, if there was a `TypeId` property which was a string or enum with values `foo` and `bar`, a style like this could be applied to the image:

```
<Style TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="foo.png" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TypeId}" Value="bar">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="bar.png" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style>
</Style>
```

Another way is to take advantage of the fact that `DataTemplate` resources defined with a `DataType` will automatically be applied to that type. But instead of having global resources that re-implement your entire template for each type, you could place a `ContentControl` within your main template, with its own local resources for just the image part:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:foo}">
            <Image Source="foo.png" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:bar}">
            <Image Source="bar.png" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a `String ImagePath` Property on your base view model and override the get accessor or set the Property in the constructor of your derived types

Comment: Funny enough, I never have thought of that. But is there no Trigger, Style or something like that which is more maintainable and easy to implement, too? I do not want to change all of the datatemplate.